# add records from a particular month

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I need to add the records for the month of July.

My code: now I can only add the records of the current month

```
$cobrosm = Cobros::whereBetween('created_at',[
            $carbon->startOfMonth()->toDateString(),
            $carbon->endOfMonth()->toDateString()
       ])->sum('importe');
```

Comment: please see this https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: I don't understand your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code :

```
$julyDate = date('Y-07-d');
$cobrosm = Cobros::whereBetween('created_at',[
        Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $julyDate)
            ->firstOfMonth()
            ->toDateString(),
        Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $julyDate)
            ->lastOfMonth()
            ->toDateString()
    ])->sum('importe');
```

For more on Carbon https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/